# Recyclerview dots indicator android

Tags: java, android

[image]

I have RecyclerView like this. I want it only shows maximum is 8 dots. But in ArrayList is have more 8 pagers for change.

I want to when I stand at 8, I change the page to 9, the 8th dots with display number is 9? and it will change to 10, 11 ...

This is my Adapter

```
public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, int layout, int number, int viewpagerposition ){
    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;
    this.number = number;
    this.viewpagerposition = viewpagerposition;
    this.numberpage = numberpage;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout, parent, false);
    RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(position == viewpagerposition){
        holder.itemView.setScaleX(1f);
        holder.itemView.setScaleY(1f);
        holder.txtrvPager.setText((position+1)+"");
        holder.txtrvPager.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rvpager_activity);
    }
    else{
        holder.itemView.setScaleX(0.5f);
        holder.itemView.setScaleY(0.5f);
        holder.txtrvPager.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rvpager_inactivity);
    }
    if(viewpagerposition > 8){

    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(number > 8){
        return 8;
    }else{
        return number;
    }

}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView txtrvPager;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtrvPager = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtrvPager);
    }
}
```

Comment: why not use view pager it better suits for this ? example library https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator

Comment: you want pagination like 8 , for each first 8 pagers then second 8 pagers right ??

Comment: @Vij he just want maximum 8 dots for any number of pages

Comment: yes i said that he wants pagination and for each page max 8 records or dots in each page ,i  already ask that thing @VivekMishra

Answer (score 0):

In your code , `getItemCount()` method return size of list, just change it to :

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
if(list.size()-1> 8){
    return 8;
}else{
    return list.size();
}

}
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: Yes, I know it, but if I stand at the last dot in 8 dots. I change to 9th page, I want the last dot will display number 9, not number 8.

Comment: ok than return 9 in getItemCount() method and check it. and debug the app on  holder.txtrvPager.setText((position+1)+"");  what position you get.